# Request with fsockopen - response without headers

Tags: php

I have method that makes url request:

```php
 public function send($httpUrl, $httpParams = [], $httpHeader = [], $waitForResponse = false)
    {
        if ($httpParams) {
            foreach ($httpParams as $key => &$val) {
                if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
                $post_params[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($val);
            }
            $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);
        }


        $parts = parse_url($httpUrl);

        if ($parts['scheme'] == 'https') {
            $parts['port'] = 5371;  // wymagany port dla nginx w php v 7.1
            $parts['url'] = "ssl://" . $parts['host'];
        }

        if (!$httpHeader['Method'])
            $httpHeader['Method'] = "GET";

        $fp = fsockopen($parts['url'],
            isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80,
            $errno, $errstr, 30);

        $out = $httpHeader['Method'] . " " . $parts['path'] . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n";
        foreach ($httpHeader AS $k => $w) {
            if ($k == 'Method') continue;
            $out .= "$k: $w\r\n";
        }
        $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $out .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        if (isset($post_string)) $out .= $post_string;

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        if ($waitForResponse) {
            $odpowiedz = '';
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $odpowiedz .= fgets($fp, 128);
            }
        } else {
            $odpowiedz = true;
        }
        fclose($fp);

        return $odpowiedz;
    }
```

Problem is that it returns response with header
like:

```
string(746) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2019 12:17:57 GMT Server: Apache Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=960d6fee4a2fcdc25520f75b2cd5d11a; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE Content-Length: 269 Connection: close Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 {"ankieta_id":6,"pytanie":"Pierwsze pytanie - dzia\u0142a?","link":"https:\/\/www.infirma.pl\/ankiety\/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhbmtpZXRhSWQiOjYsImtsaWVudElkIjoxLCJ1enl0a293bmlrSWQiOjEsImV4cCI6MTU3MzgyMDI3N30.4zXu0e9ns4OZC0f5ITD9XoTd8TS3zUROOSVjiKnebdU"}"
```

I don't want headers only json string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read the response. Change the fgets part with the following code:

```
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $odpowiedz .= fread($this->socket, 1024);
}
```

Then, you can use the following code to strip only the body part:

```
$crlf = "\r\n";
$position = strpos($response, $crlf.$crlf);
$content = substr($response, $position + 2 * strlen($crlf));
```

Comment: `fread()` seems not to load whole response. But Your further code works.

Comment: @piernik Because you need to use it within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fgets.php) which will read to a line terminator or EOF.
So you wont have the lines in your code.

you should use [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fread.php) instead to split later the header and the body.